# IInAppBillingService Program type already present

Tags: java, android, gradle, in-app-billing, android-multidex

I just updated my CompileSDKVersion and TargetSDK Version to 27, and updated the dependencies accordingly, and now my app won't run, it's getting this error:

```
Program type already present: com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

I'm using a billing library called [checkout](https://github.com/serso/android-checkout).   I've tried reverting back to 26 and disabling certain dependencies but nothing seems to work.

**My App Level Build.Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.paxana.cwnet"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 9
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.0.0'

    implementation 'org.solovyev.android:checkout:1.2.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.5.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.anthonymandra:ToggleButtons:2.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.0.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:5.0.6.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**my project level build.gradle**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot' }


        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4'
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```